# Arabic characters displayed as symbols in CSV file. C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

```
var result = await profileManager.GetCSVAsByteResults(searchOptions); // return array of bytes
            
if (result == null || result.Length == 0)
{
    return NotFound();
}
var finalResult = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble().Concat(result).ToArray();
return File(finalResult, "text/csv", $"UserProfiles.{DateTime.Now:yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss}.csv");
```

**GetCSVAsByteResults method**

```
public static byte[] GetCSVAsByteResults<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
        {
            using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memory, new UTF8Encoding(true)))
            using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer))
            {
                csvWriter.WriteRecords<T>(data);
                writer.Flush();
                var result = memory.ToArray();
                return result;
            }
        }
```

the CSV file contains Arabic letters but they are displayed as symbols I tried what I find while searching  on the internet and still have the same problem.

Comment: How does `GetCSVAsByteResults` work? What encoding is the file?

Comment: This sounds like an `Encoding` problem. What is writing the CSV, and what is reading it? Do they both agree on the encoding? And: what encoding is that? (not all encodings support all characters). CSV is a text format, and there isn't a hard "so you write the bytes like this" - so it isn't enough to say "array of bytes" - we need to know *how* those bytes were written (and we also need to know what tool you're using to view the csv once downloaded - the problem could be entirely at the consumer end)

Comment: @Llama the encoding of `GetCSVAsByteResults` is `UTF8Encoding(true)`

Comment: @MarcGravell I open the CSV file in excel the encoding of the file is UTF8 if I changed manually to UT8-BOM then i open it in excel I get the result that i need

Comment: Where the letters are displayed as symbols?

Comment: it is curious that your BOM prefix (`GetPreamble()` etc) doesn't seem to have worked, but: if the data contains a UTF8 BOM, this sounds like a problem in Excel

Comment: @MarcGravell when I check the encoding of the CSV file I found it UTF8 is there a way to ensure that the encoding of the  created file is UTF8-BOM.(I also added a code block of the (GetCSVAsByteResults method)

Comment: @MaciejLos when I open the CSV file in excel

Comment: @someone you're already including the UTF 8 BOM - although it *looks* like you're actually including the BOM **twice** (once via `GetPreamble()`, once via the `StreamWriter`). You might want to check the first 6 bytes of the downloaded file; `EF-BB-BF` once (then something else) is good; but twice (i.e. `EF-BB-BF-EF-BB-BF`) is bad. If you have the BOM once and once only and it still isn't working: that's an Excel problem.

Comment: @MarcGravell I will check that Thank you